# PHP scripts stops extraordinarily in crontab

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I set a cron to run this script. I used recursion to update a table (250 rows every time). It runs well at the beginning but after some minutes, it stops without printing "Finish". It seems to be a memory problem of server. I checked "Processes" in PhpMyadmin and make sure it runs well but it stops after some minutes. How to fix it?

```
function update_mt_image_inventory($db, $from)
{
    $current_img_id = htmlentities($_SERVER['argv'][1], ENT_QUOTES);  
    if(!$current_img_id) $current_img_id = 999999999;   
    $interier = 250;
    $sql = "SELECT im.IMG_ID, im.IMG_FILENAME, im.SEAL_NUMBER , im.XXX FROM `mt_images` im WHERE im.IMG_ID < {$current_img_id} AND im.ACT_FLG = 1 ORDER BY im.IMG_ID DESC LIMIT {$from}, {$interier}";
    $re_check = @$db->sql_query($sql);
    if(@mysql_num_rows($re_check) > 0) {
        while($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($re_check)) {
            $img_id =  $row['IMG_ID'];
            $current_img_id = $img_id;:q!
            $inventory =  $row['XXX'];

            $sql = "SELECT USER_ID FROM tr_lines_alls WHERE IMG_ID = {$img_id} AND ACT_FLG = 1";
            $img_res = @$db->sql_query($sql);
            $img_count = @mysql_num_rows($img_res) ;
            if($img_count != $inventory && $img_id>0){
                $sql = "UPDATE mt_images SET XXX = {$img_count} WHERE IMG_ID = {$img_id}";
                @$db->sql_query($sql);
                $data = "{$img_id} | {$inventory} | {$img_count}";
                echo $data."\n";
                if($img_count>0) writeLog($data);
            }
            @mysql_free_result($img_res);
            unset($img_res);
        }
        @mysql_free_result($re_check);
        unset($re_check);
        echo "Checking next {$interier}/{$from} - Current: {$current_img_id} - Memory: ".memory_get_usage(false)."\n"; 
        if($from%5000 ==0){
            echo date("h:i:s")." --> 5000 records passed.\n";
        }
        update_mt_image_inventory($db, $from + $interier);
    } else {
        writeLog("mt_images finished");
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, remove `@` everywhere.

Comment: maybe you could save the output of the cron inside a file to see if theres a Php error, something like `1 * * * * * php myscript.php > output.log`

Comment: +1 for @sanmai's comment. The `@` suppresses error messages, so your script might just crash silently.

Comment: I'm sure it is not syntax error problem because when I run it without using cron. It runs well and print text out to console. BTW how to set bounty for this question?

Comment: It doesnt have to be a syntax error, it can also be a mysql error.
For instance: what if an insert goes wrong (because of a foreign key constraint or something like that) and you try mysql_affected_rows on the result of that query. It will crash, but you wont know why.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying your solution. I ran it many years with no problem but when using in cron it doesn't end. Could it be memory problem? Each table has about 19 millions rows.

Answer (score 2):

Could be the time limit setting.
Try this on the first line of your code:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Comment: PHP Cli default time limit is 0: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.differences.php

Comment: I know... but it could be the case that on his server the value for time limit is not the default. 
He says there is no error or anything so the most logical cause would be the time limit.